# How can I use scp from an ipv6 server to download from an ipv4 server?

Tags: server, ipv6, scp, ipv4

I know the -6 option to download from an ipv6 server, the problem is that *i'm on an ipv6 server* , and try to download from an ipv4 server, how can I do it ?

Here's the command that I use :  `scp -r username@address:~/files .`

The same command I use it in an ipv4 server to download from another ipv4 server and it works, but when I do it in an ipv6 server it doesnt.

I receive this error: ssh: connect to host *ipv4 server* port 22: Connection timed out

Thank you for your help, and i'm here if you need any more informations.

Comment: Do you have IPv4 connectivity on your "IPv6 server"? If so, you can use the `-4` option of scp: "
     -4      Forces scp to use IPv4 addresses only.
"

Comment: No, unfortunately I dont have one .

Comment: @FedonKadifeli that is the way to do it.  Use the lowest possible method that is acceptable for all servers. Either both need to support ipv4 or both need to support ipv6.

Comment: @Rinzwind I dont have an ipv4, it's an ipv6 only server.

Comment: @assilmanss then you will need this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_transition_mechanism   DNS64 + NAT64. and it will be 1 way : ipv6 to ipv4 not the other way :)

Comment: @Rinzwind Ok, i'm gonna read it and try to do it , as I have root in my ipv6 server.

Comment: @Rinzwind Found it quite hard to do it, is there any other way ? Thank you for your help

Comment: You can use *another* server in between which has both ipv4 and ipv6 connectivity as a "gateway".

Comment: @FedonKadifeli can you pls explain it more, this sounds like a good idea !

Comment: I haven't tried, but I think the `ProxyCommand` can be used for this. You can Google for "scp ProxyCommand" to find some already given answers to your problem. But, you need to have a server with ssh access and connected to internet both with IPv4 and IPv6. See also https://superuser.com/questions/174160/ for example...

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Thank you ! I appreciate very much your help !